# How does createStore extract initialState from reducer function in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was going through the code of redux, `createStore.js`, I am not able to figure out how it extracts the initial state from reducer function. If the initial state is specified in reducer function as 1st argument.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L31

the code is initiating `currentState` from `preloadedState`, but I am not able to find how it extracts it from reducer function.

for example reducer function is:

```js
const counter = ( state = 2, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INCREMENT':
        return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;   
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial state isn't 'extracted' from a reducer. Due to how a reducer works, a state is always transformed by a reducer. This is done on store creation, too, because [`INIT` internal action is dispatched](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/55f1d08000b1b064eaa933bbbd132230e53bcccb/src/createStore.js#L242). In case a state is `undefined`, it's initialized with default value specified in reducer parameter.

Comment: where does it doing in code? I am not able to figure out that

Comment: Are you referring to this code, https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L31 ? Most of it handles combinations of optional `createStore` arguments, https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer .

Comment: so when action with "INIT" type dispatched by default this [call](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/55f1d08000b1b064eaa933bbbd132230e53bcccb/src/createStore.js#L170) sets the initial state, right?

Comment: That's correct - as long as you have `default:
     return state;` thing. That's the good reason to always have it in a reducer.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clarification. I should have reviewed code more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Redux connect Method fire an event name INIT with an undefined state so if you replaced undefined with your own state it replaces that. that's why default: case is there so it can return your initial state. 
read more about connect() method REDUX.

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/f8b48cf3caa96c531f1bb572d9ad8986a03fe367/src/createStore.js#L272

in createStore.js you can see default INIT is fired.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks, I figured out it late

Answer (score 1):

In your example reducer function

```
const counter = (state = 2, action) => ...
```

You are actually not passing in a default state per se, but setting a default value for the state.

The function can be rewritten into this:

```
const counter = (state, action) => {
  if (state == null) state = 2; // not good practice, just for illustration purpose
  ...
}
```

So when the reducer is passed to ‘createStore’, createStore just run the reducer; state argument is undefined so it’s set to `2`.

The Redux docs may clear things up a bit more:

> Reducers can also specify an initial value by looking for an incoming state argument that is undefined, and returning the value they'd like to use as a default. This can either be done with an explicit check inside the reducer, or by using the ES6 default argument value syntax: function myReducer(state = someDefaultValue, action).

[redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)